# Is there any free database with natural language texts and their authors?

Tags: nlp

I need some public database to get pairs text-author for text authorship research. Don't want manually search books and insert corresponding record in database.

Comment: I would be interested in an answer as well. Unfortunately your request is off-topic for SO. But because I cannot designate an alternative I hope for an answer before this question is closed.

Comment: Questions about datasets could be better suited for the AI stack exchange: https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Text authorship corpus" returns several promising hits in Google. Try Gutenberg corpus as a search term, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaggle datasets is good starting source for publicly available data sets. Here's the dataset for the [spooky author identification competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/spooky-author-identification/data) that could be useful but it does not have many authors.